# site_url and $current_user producing undesired results

Tags: php

I am trying to make the link like this: `site.com/forums/user/userid` using the code below. I think I messed it up though because it keeps producing an error on this line.

`$buttons['Edit My Profile']    =  site_url('/forums/user/')$current_user->user_login;`

Here is more of the surrounding code:

```
    <?php

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $buttons    = array();

        if ( $sl_options['show_dashboard'] )
            $buttons['Dashboard']   = admin_url();

        if ( $sl_options['show_profile'] )
            $buttons['Edit My Profile'] =  site_url('/forums/user/')$current_user->user_login; 

        $buttons['Log Out'] = ( $sl_options['redirect_logout'] == 'custom' && $sl_options['redirect_logout_url'] != '' ) ? wp_logout_url( $sl_options['redirect_logout_url'] ) : wp_logout_url( $this->current_url() );         

        ?>
```

Can somebody please take a look and let me know where I went wrong on that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the [**concatenation operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Your code should look like this:

```
$buttons['Edit My Profile'] = site_url('/forums/user/') . $current_user->user_login;
```